# Which row is updated first?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-order-by

I update more rows by `UPDATE` statement in MSSQL. I'd like to know which row is the first updated one.

---

*Details:*

*I am having troubles with a trigger written by someone else. It doesn't proceed for one row. The trigger is fired by UPDATE to all rows (~30k) excluding those which were already sucessfully updated before. The problematic row is now the next one which is supposed to be updated. I need to find the row somehow. Is there some way?*

*I've read a few posts how to imitated `UPDATE` with `ORDER BY` and it didn't work for me.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is a set language. there are no 'first', 'previous' or 'next' concepts. All rows are updated simultaneously.

Comment: It appears to be done simultaneously. It should be. But, it isn’t physically possible.
The trigger feeds a webservice, which saves data to another system. All the data doesn’t appear in the second system in a moment. The row number in the other system is increasing gradually. I had to wait for the mistaken row long time to take a turn. Now, it is the next one to go.
But since the concepts is as you told; this probably isn’t the right way to go.

Comment: "The trigger feeds a webservice" everything after that is mute. web service calls from triggers are absolutely worse mistake one can make. Inefficient (will slow down operations as they have to wait for slow HTTP responses), High Unavailability built-in (HTTP failures causes DML failures) and, most importantly, incorrect (rollbacks can occur *long* after the trigger finished, but the HTTP call cannot be undone).